# Disable jQuery hover within CSS Media Query

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I'm aware i probably cant execute jQuery within a CSS file. But here is my conundrum:

I have several divs with overlays on them. On a desktop the user hovers over the overlay and it slides up revealing content.

On a mobile, there isnt a hover state (gracefully implemented). How can i use my existing Media Query logic to disable jQuery hover on those certain divs?

Any advice welcome, or even for an alternative solution to this problem?

Comment: It's a better idea to use JavaScript for this, though you may not be able to detect with the exact same conditions as media queries...

Answer (score 1):

Your code quite probably look like this while running :

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item show" />
    <div class="item hide" />
    <div class="item hide" />
    <div class="item hide" />
    <div class="item hide" />
</div>
```

with *hide* being something like `display:none`
and *show* being `display:block`

Just change *hide* to `display:block` in the good Media Query and mobile user will see all the content! (might have to disable the JS too)

I want to scold you *lightly* for not putting up any code and having 4k rep :)

Comment: Scolding appreciated. I figured it was more of a conceptual question than an actual code problem :)

Comment: My only issue is that I wasn't sure of what you really wanted.